# unbind excel on super + e keyboard shortcut

Tags: release-loki, keyboard-shortcuts, wine

I've installed MS Office 2010 using CrossOver, before super + E was bound to open `home folder` but now when I press super + e its opening MS Excel. How to unbind the MS Excel?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply rebind the keyboard shortcut to open your home folder. This will automatically disable the other one.

Comment: I already did that on the keyboard shortcut, it didn't do the trick. Its fixed now though, what happened was excel was set as the `default file/folder manager`. I think I accidentally assign it when Im associating the .xlx(s) files to excel.

Thanks for helping out though, anwering silly question ;) I appreciate it.

Comment: You might want to delete or reformulate your question as actually there is no question: Excel was the default file/folder manager, so folders were supposed to open with Excel…